# pHp sign up not working?

Tags: php, html, mysql

Okay, so I am trying to make a sign up page that:
Creates a personal table and then adds the user to the "login" table
What happens is the page goes blank (As I wan't it to) But it still never makes the table or ad the user

Code in Sign4.php:

```
<?php

$host="localhost";
$username = "robx10ho_users";
$password = "stackoverflow";
$db_name="robx10ho_usersuse"; 
$tbl_name="login";

// Connect to server and select databse.
mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

// Define $myusername and $mypassword 
$myusername=$_POST['myusername']; 
$mypassword=$_POST['mypassword']; 

// To protect MySQL injection (more detail about MySQL injection)
$myusername = stripslashes($myusername);
$mypassword = stripslashes($mypassword);
$myusername = mysql_real_escape_string($myusername);
$mypassword = mysql_real_escape_string($mypassword);
$sql="SELECT * FROM $tbl_name WHERE Username='$myusername' and Password='$mypassword'";
$result=mysql_query($sql);

// Mysql_num_row is counting table row
$count=mysql_num_rows($result);

// If result matched $myusername and $mypassword, table row must be 1 row
if($count==1){
echo "Hello, ".$myusername.". This is your account list: "."<br>";
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($host, $username, $password, $db_name);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT Username, Password, Membership FROM ".$myusername;
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo "Username: " . $row["Username"]. " | Password: " . $row["Password"]. " | Membership:" . $row["Membership"]. "<br>";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}

mysqli_close($conn);
}
else {
CREATE TABLE $myusername (
Username TEXT(300) NOT NULL,
Password TEXT(300) NOT NULL,
Membership TEXT(500) NOT NULL
)

INSERT INTO login ($myusername, $mypassword)
}
?>
```

This is the code that I put inside of the file Signup.php:

```
<table width="300" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#00ffff" style="-webkit-border-radius: 10-moz-border-radius: 10;border-radius: 10px;font-family: Arial;color: #00ffff;font-size: 11px;padding: 10px 17px 10px 17px;">
<tr>
<form name="form1" method="post" action="http://rob.x10host.com/Sign4.php">
<td>
<table width="100%" border="0" cellpadding="3" cellspacing="1" bgcolor="#FFFFFF">
<tr>
<td colspan="3"><strong>Login to database. </strong></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="78">Username: </td>
<td width="294"><input name="myusername" type="text" id="myusername"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>Password: </td>
<td><input name="mypassword" type="password" id="mypassword"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td>&nbsp;</td>
<td><input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Sign Up" style="  background: #d93434;background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top, #d93434, #ff0000);background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(top, #d93434, #ff0000);background-image: -ms-linear-gradient(top, #d93434, #ff0000);background-image: -o-linear-gradient(top, #d93434, #ff0000);background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #d93434, #ff0000);-webkit-border-radius: 10-moz-border-radius: 10;border-radius: 10px;font-family: Arial;color: #ffffff;font-size: 11px;padding: 6px 17px 6px 17px;text-decoration: none;"></td>
</tr>
</table>
</td>
</form>
</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You're mixing `php` and `sql`. You need to run the sql commands via a library (i.e `PDO`/`MySQLi`). In your case, you need to use `mysqli_query()` to execute them...

Comment: Where do i put that?

Comment: Where you're doing the whole `CREATE TABLE ..... INSERT INTO`, also btw, your `INSERT` query won't work. It needs to be something like: `INSERT INTO table (username, password) VALUES($username, $password)` or something similar.

Comment: what line I put it everywhere!

Comment: Why do people still learn database connection using `mysql_` functions? Why learn something that is bad and deprecated instead of something better and current (like PDO/mysqli)? It just goes above me

Comment: __Do not__ create a new table for every user. Create one table and add all the users' data to it, referenced by user name or some other unique key. What you're doing will quickly prove to be entirely unmanageable and very slow.

Answer (score 0):

```
$sql = "CREATE TABLE $myusername (Username TEXT(300) NOT NULL, Password TEXT(300) NOT NULL, Membership TEXT(500) NOT NULL)";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    echo "Table $myusername created successfully";
    $sql = "INSERT INTO login ($myusername, $mypassword)";

    if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
        echo "New user created successfully";
    } else {
        echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
    }
} else {
    echo "Error creating table: " . mysqli_error($conn);
}
```

Comment: Replace your content of your last else block with this code, it should work. Btw i think you should also check if table allready exist http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-tablename.php

Comment: Please incorporate additions into your answer. Use the [edit button](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/27894255/edit). Answers are more useful to future readers if they contain some explanation text, not just code/bugfixes only usable to the question asker.